# E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lua5.3'

Tags: debian, lua

I have a new Debian Jessie machine, but when I try to install Lua (5.3) through `apt` I get this error:

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading stateinformation... Done
>
> E: Unable to locate package lua5.3
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lua5.3'

I've been looking through Mr. Google to find out some information, but couldn't find anything

---

```
barreeeiroo@Telegram /etc> sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list
#

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.1.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20150606-14:16]/ jessie main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.1.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20150606-14:16]/ jessie main

deb http://mirror.unitedcolo.de/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://mirror.unitedcolo.de/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://mirror.unitedcolo.de/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb-src http://mirror.unitedcolo.de/debian/ jessie-updates main
barreeeiroo@Telegram /etc>
```

Comment: Welcome to SE , please [edit here](https://superuser.com/posts/1262366/edit) by adding the output of `cat /etc/sources.list`

Comment: Hi @GAD3R
I edited it, check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install [`lua5.3`](https://packages.debian.org/fr/jessie-backports/lua5.3) from jessie backports :

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following line;

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

Save <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> ; <kbd>Enter</kbd> ; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -t jessie-backports install lua5.3
```